# How to assign a LARGE_INTEGER* to LARGE__INTEGER?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have been try for sometime now of assigning a `LARGE_INTEGER*` to `LARGE_INTEGER` type but cannot do that.

I tried

```
Dir->Siz = (LARGE_INTEGER)Siz;
```

Where `Dir->Siz` is `LARGE_INTEGER` and `Siz` is of type `LARGE_INTEGER*`. But that's not acceptable.

Can anyone help?

Error:

```
error C2670: binary "=": no operator found which takes a right-hand operator of type 'PLARGE_INTEGER' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: What is `LARGE_INTEGER`?

Comment: `Dir->Siz = *Siz;`

Comment: @timrau https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sigh, 1.2 billion computers that use millions of times every day it is not enough in the [c++] tag.

Comment: @tim what does it matter, the answer is the same no matter what the type is

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The first version of the question was about `*LARGE_INTEGER` and `LARGE_INTEGER` while error message was about `PLARGE_INTEGER`. That's quite confusing.

Comment: @timrau in winapi, they like to prefix pointer type of something with 'P' or 'LP' for example `LPDWORD` means `DWORD*`.

Answer (score 4):

Try `Dir->Siz = *Siz;`. Use dereference operator `*` to dereference pointer back to object.

Comment: My bad. Should have seen that. 